# How to organize two steps confirmation? node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, authorization

I have the node.js server that proceeds cash operations.
I want to make the user confirmation of cash transactions.
I provide this feature to prevent user mistakes.

Step 1: User inputs some values into the html form,
then server gets values from this form(e.g. post query), prepares it and sends back to the user.

Step 2: User checks received data and press "OK" or "Cancel", depends on it the server uses the data, received on step 1 in a special way.

My problems are: Connection between step 1 and step 2 on the server side. 
Where should I store the data from step 1 until step 2?

Or can you advise me another logic in this situation?

Comment: P.S. I use passport js to authorize users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a session that comes from passport.js for the user, so you would typically save the data temporarily as a property on the session object for that user.  Then, on the confirmation, you can retrieve the data from the session and continue the process.

You may want to also have some logic that removes the extra data from session after some timeout if there is no confirming response from the user within some period of time.  Of, you could just leave it there until the session itself times out.

There's a lot written in this article [ExpressJS and PassportJS Sessions Deep Dive](https://www.airpair.com/express/posts/expressjs-and-passportjs-sessions-deep-dive) about how to add more properties to the session.  Depending upon your passport configuration, it may be as simple as just adding a property to `req.user` or it may be slightly more involved.

Comment: @IgorKasuan - Did this answer your question?